# Decomposing time series signals on Python without "losing" data in the trend component i.e. without centered moving averages?

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, decomposition

I am trying to run an online change point detection on the trend component of a time series signal (so I don't get false positives due to seasonality). The seasonal_decompose from statsmodels returns NaN values for trend component at the beginning and end due to CMA under the hood.
Is there a way to get the trend without losing any data? I want to check changes on a daily level so need updated data

I have tried stl from statsmodels, same issue

Additional details:
I have a df with dates and corresponding values for over 4 years (sample below):

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 01.01.2019 | 50 |
| 02.01.2019 | 51 |
| 03.01.2019 | 52 |
| 04.01.2019 | 53 |

I am then decomposing the signal using seasonal_decompose from statsmodels and then applying change point detection from ruptures:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

ts = df['value'].values
result = seasonal_decompose(ts, model='additive', period=365)  #yearly seasonality

trend_component = result.trend

valid_indices = ~np.isnan(trend_component)
trend_component_np = trend_component[valid_indices].reshape(-1, 1)

detector = rpt.Pelt(model="l2").fit(trend_component_np)
change_points = detector.predict(pen=150)
```

When I plot the trend and residual components, it gives me NaN values in the first/last 6 months. I have more than 2 cycles of data, why is this happening? Seasonality is populated.

 Looking for alternative methods too.

Comment: The problem sounds like it is in either the Python statsmodel implementation of seasonal_decompose or how you are using it. It is impossible to known which without some sample code and a minimal reproducible example. Nans in your results generally means that something has gone horribly wrong and no half decent numerical package should ever produce them without providing some clue as to why. Even with garbage in there should be error messages out. The usual way to deal with seasonal variation is fold and average the data over the fundamental period. It should not result in Nans.

Comment: It's the seasonal_decompose implementation in Python, someone talks about this here: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3872. I do have 2 full cycles, several years of data actually.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi! I added additional details. Thanks!

Comment: One thing that helped me remove the latest NaNs is setting "two_sided" parameter as False. From the documentation:
two_sidedbool
The moving average method used in filtering. If True (default), a centered moving average is computed using the filt. If False, the filter coefficients are for past values only.
extrapolate_trend
If set to > 0, the trend resulting from the convolution is linear least-squares extrapolated on both ends (or the single one if two_sided is False) considering this many (+1) closest points. Setting this parameter results in no NaN values in trend or resid components.